# MOQ SetupGet dbContext with constructor parameters

Tags: c#, mocking, entity-framework-core, moq, xunit

**Situation**

Here I am, trying to write some unit tests for my `GroupService` with the use of MOQ.

To create an instance of my `GroupService`, I mocked 4 interfaces that needed to be passed through the constructor. Now on one of the mocks (`IGroupRepository`) a property called `Context` is called and my idea was to `SetupGet` this property and just simply return a fake list of `GroupUser`. But I keep getting errors, whatever I try.

**Code**

```
public class GroupServiceTests
{
    private readonly GroupService _groupService;
    private readonly Mock<AppDbContext> _dbContext;
    private readonly Mock<IGroupRepository> _groupRepository;
    private readonly Mock<IComponentService> _componentService;
    private readonly Mock<IUserContextService> _userContextService;
    private readonly Mock<IModelEntityMapper<Group, Core.DbContexts.Entities.Group>> _mapper;

    public GroupServiceTests()
    {
        var groupUsersMock = CreateDbSetMock(GetFakeListOfGroupUsers());
        _dbContext = new Mock<AppDbContext>(new DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>());
        _dbContext.SetupGet(x => x.GroupUser).Returns(groupUsersMock.Object);

        _groupRepository = new Mock<IGroupRepository>();
        _groupRepository.SetupGet(repo => repo.Context).Returns(_dbContext.Object);

        _componentService = new Mock<IComponentService>();
        _userContextService = new Mock<IUserContextService>();
        _mapper = new Mock<IModelEntityMapper<Group, Core.DbContexts.Entities.Group>>();

        _groupService = new GroupService(_groupRepository.Object, _componentService.Object, _userContextService.Object, _mapper.Object);
    }
}
```

In the `GroupService` this line is called:

```
// _repository reffers to IGroupRepository
userIdsForContextReset.AddRange(_repository.Context.GroupUser.Where(x => groupIds.Contains(x.GroupId)).Select(x => x.UserId));
```

And the `GroupRepository` and `EntityRepository` look like this:

```
public interface IGroupRepository : IEntityRepository<AppDbContext, Group>
{
    List<GroupPermission> GetInheritedGroupPermissions(int groupId);
}

public class GroupRepository : EntityRepository<AppDbContext, Group>, IGroupRepository
{
    public GroupRepository(AppDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public List<GroupPermission> GetInheritedGroupPermissions(int groupId)
    {
        // Removed for brevity
    }
}
```

```
public class EntityRepository<TDbContext, TEntity> : EntityRepository<TDbContext, TEntity, int>, IEntityRepository<TDbContext, TEntity>
     where TDbContext : DbContext
     where TEntity : class, IEntity<int>
{
    public EntityRepository(TDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

```
public class EntityRepository<TDbContext, TEntity, TId> : IEntityRepository<TDbContext, TEntity, TId>
     where TDbContext : DbContext
     where TEntity : class, IEntity<TId>
     where TId : IComparable
{
    public EntityRepository(TDbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public TDbContext Context { get; }
}
```

And last but not least, the `AppDbContext` and `SqlDbContext`:

```
public class AppDbContext : Shared.DbContexts.SqlDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<GroupUser> GroupUser { get; set; }

    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

```
public class SqlDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SqlDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
        ChangeTracker.StateChanged += ChangeTracker_StateChanged;
    }
}
```

**Error**

The error that I am getting is inside the `SqlDbContext` on the 1st line inside the constructor and says the following:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you mock an implementation it creates the object using the constructor matching the parameters provided; it runs that code.
Additionally, anything not able to be mocked (not virtual or abstract) will run as is. In this case, you're passing in DbContextOptions and you haven't specified a provider, and something needs that.

This can be an opinionated topic, however to solve your problem there are a number of ways you could do it:

1. Add a parameterless constructor to your DbContext for testing. I wouldn't recommend this as I follow the mantra of not changing your SUT for a test.
2. Use an in-memory provider; [EF Core In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) or [SQLite EF Core Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) are two that I have used. They do have limitations but for the OP usage would probably be fine and addresses Microsofts notes about how you shouldn't [mock the DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/#unit-testing).
3. Use an existing library such as [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) (disclaimer, I am the author) which will extend in-memory providers to address their limitations.

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer! One question about your first answer... I had to change the data field to Virtual to be able to use it in my tests. Is this also against the mantra of not changing your SUT for a test? And how should this be avoided?

Comment: Which data field? The GroupUser property on your context? It's fairly common for that to be virtual, in fact it's how efcore scaffolds the context when using the db first methodology